# ExpressJS app.get('*', function(req,res){}) is handling all the requests

Tags: javascript, express

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
res.redirect('/myPage');});
```

This code I have added to end of the main.js. However, this code is handling even the routes defined above in the file.

Comment: change the order of declaration of the routes, put the * at the end

Comment: @Ricardo: post as answer?

Comment: This code is already at the end of the file

Comment: If it's already at the end, then you'll need to post the full `app.js` or similar so we can see whatever else you're defining.

Answer (score 4):

Got it working by taking app.use(router) to top. It was previously below my code.
I don't know why it happened but now its working fine.